# find common elements in two lists in linear time complexity

Tags: python, list

I have two unsorted lists of integers without duplicates both of them contain the same elements but not in the same order and I want to find the indices of the common elements between the two lists in lowest time complexity. For example

```
a = [1, 8, 5, 3, 4]
b = [5, 4, 1, 3, 8]
```

the output should be :

```
list1[0] With list2[2]
list1[1] With list2[4]
list1[2] With list2[0]
and so on
```

I have thought of using set. intersection and then find the index using the 'index' function but I didn't know how to print the output in a right way

this is what I've tried

```
b = set(list1).intersection(list2)
ina = [list1.index(x) for x in b]
inb = [list2.index(x) for x in b]
print (ina , inb )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find them in linear time you should use some kind of hashing. The easiest way in Python is to use a dict:

```
list1 = [1, 8, 5, 3, 4]
list2 = [5, 4, 1, 3, 8]

common = set(list1).intersection(list2)
dict2 = {e: i for i, e in enumerate(list2) if e in common}
result = [(i, dict2[e]) for i, e in enumerate(list1) if e in common]
```

The `result` will be

```
[(0, 2), (1, 4), (2, 0), (3, 3), (4, 1)]
```

You can use something like this to format and print it:

```
for i1, i2 in result:
    print(f"list1[{i1}] with list2[{i2}]")
```

you get:

```
list1[0] with list2[2]
list1[1] with list2[4]
list1[2] with list2[0]
list1[3] with list2[3]
list1[4] with list2[1]
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a dictionary that maps elements of one list to their indexes. Then update it to have the indexes of the corresponding elements of the other list. Then any element that has two indices is in the intersection.

```
intersect = {x: [i] for i, x in enumerate(list1)}
for i, x in enumerate(list2):
    if x in intersect:
        intersect[x].append(i)
for l in intersect.values():
    if len(l) == 2:
        print(f'list1[{l[0]}] with list2[{l[1]}]')
```

Comment: I don't think this would print the indices in the correct order.

Comment: @Selcuk I thought he just wanted to get the two lists of indexes. I've updated it to print the corresponding indexes.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [1, 8, 5, 3, 4]
b = [5, 4, 1, 3, 8]

e2i = {e : i for (i, e) in enumerate(b)}
for i, e in enumerate(a):
    if e in e2i:
        print('list1[%d] with list2[%d]' % (i, e2i[e]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on the excellent answers here, you can squeeze a little more juice out of the lemon by not bothering to record the indices of `a`. (Those indices are just `0` through `len(a) - 1` anyway and you can add them back later if needed.)

```
e2i = {e : i for (i, e) in enumerate(b)}
output = [e2i.get(e) for e in enumerate(a)]
output
# [2, 4, 0, 3, 1]
```

With `len(a) == len(b) == 5000` on my machine this code runs a little better than twice as fast as Björn Lindqvist's code (after I modified his code to store the output rather than print it).